# Release git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

Al utilizar git-flow y finalizar un release me pone el release con un tag de la siguiente forma.

`The release was tagged '0.0.11.0.0'`

La primera parte que dice 0.0.1 no la puse yo en ningun momento dentro de mi proyecto pero la segunda parte que es la que yo quiero agregar le agrega esa primera parte del tag.

Solamente use los comandos `git flow release start 1.0.0` y para finalizarlo use `git flow release finish 1.0.0`.